# How can I set the local default value in defineProps?

Tags: internationalization, vuejs3

I've trying to set the default value of a prop to a local value using `i18n`. I'm using Vue 3.2 and the script setup tag.

I've tried the following but this gives me an error:

> defineProps are referencing locally declared variables.

```js
<script setup>
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
    
const { t } = useI18n();
    
defineProps({
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: false, default: `${t('oops', 1)} ${t('request_error', 1)}` },
  description: { type: String, required: false, default: '' },
  showReload: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
  error: { type: String, required: true },
});
</script>
```

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`defineProps` is a compiler macro, so you can't use any runtime values within it. I'd suggest to use a local variable for this default:

```js
<script setup>
    import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

    const props = defineProps({
        type: { type: String, required: true },
        title: { type: String, required: false},
        description: { type: String, required: false, default: '' },
        showReload: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
        error: { type: String, required: true },
    });


    const { t } = useI18n();
    const titleWithDefault = props.title || `${t('oops', 1)} ${t('request_error', 1)}`;
</script>
```

Also described here in the last bullet point: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-and-defineemits

Comment: I'm late to the discussion. I like your solution, @Thomas, but if the title prop ever changes, it will go unnoticed in `titleWithDefault`. Using `computed` will help keep it reactive.

Answer (score 24):

### How to define props with default

first, if you want Default props values when using type declaration use this:

```js
export interface Props {
  msg?: string
  labels?: string[]
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  msg: 'hello',
  labels: () => ['one', 'two']
})
```

Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76662617/how-can-the-default-value-for-props-be-defined-in-vue-3)

learn more [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features)

### How to define props with default ( reference locally declared variables )

The solution is to import i18n and use it directly

```js
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'


export interface Props {
  msg?: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  msg: () => useI18n().t('message')
})
```

**In this solution you don't lose reactivity**

Comment: Your answer is correct in it's assertion of how to set default props, but the question was about how to make the default of a prop some i18n string.