# How can the default value for props be defined in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How can I define the default value of a prop in the Vue 3 setup script?

```
interface InputProps {
  message: string
  error?: string
}

const props = defineProps<InputProps>()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a Default Value using `withDefaults` in the Vue 3 Composition API:

```
interface InputProps {
  message: string
  error?: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<InputProps>(), {
  message: null
})
```

learn more [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features)